# What is equivalent of ajax id attribute in Richfaces 4?

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

In richfaces 3 their is a4j support which contain id attribute,on which we trigger our action listeners,but in richfaces 4 there is no id attribute in ajax,how i trigger my action on id.

I have made a class in with i created a method to trigger action class with id.
for e.g

i have stored action classes in a map with id and class
MAP = {GETZIPCODE,class}

When a action is invoke i get the id from actionevent.getid from a4jsupport and fetch the action class from map on behalf of id.

But in richfaces 4 i have no attribute of id in a4j:ajax,thats why i am not able to trigger action.

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code? I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you're trying to pass a parameter to the listener, try `listener=#{bean.action('myId')}` - but why aren't you calling different listeners for distinct tasks (because that's what I get you're after)?